# UISearchController takes the wrong table view

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

So this is my code, I have view controller that delegates a table view named complexTable. for some reason, the UISearchController looks up `self.tableView` instead of `self.complexTable`. I could not find where I can set its table view to match the one my view controller delegates. 
Another important explanation for understanding this code is the `manager` variable - it holds another `Array<SidebarComplex>` object.

Ultimately, I would like to have a command that is somewhat like this:

```
self.searchDisplayController.table = self.complexTable
```

but I did not find anything like that. Also some delegates for the search bar are declared in storyboard but I do not really understand what they refer to.

```
import UIKit
let COMPLEX_IDENTIFIER = "SideBarComplexCell"
class SideBarViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var complexTable: UITableView!

var complexSearchResults: Array<SidebarComplex> = []

var manager = SidebarManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    complexTable.dataSource = self
    complexTable.delegate = self
    complexTable.tableFooterView = UIView()
    manager.fetch()

    self.searchDisplayController!.delegate = self
    self.complexTable.reloadData()
}

}

extension SideBarViewController: UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate{


func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {

    self.complexSearchResults = self.manager.complexArray.filter({( complex: SidebarComplex) -> Bool in
        return complex.name!.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText.lowercaseString) != nil
    })
}


func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String?) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString!)
    return true
}

}

extension SideBarViewController:  UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = complexTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(COMPLEX_IDENTIFIER) as! SideBarComplexCell

    var complexArray: Array<SidebarComplex>
    if complexTable == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        complexArray = self.complexSearchResults //This is never called even when I search.
    } else {
        complexArray = self.manager.complexArray
    }
    if complexArray.count > indexPath.section {

        let complex = complexArray[indexPath.section]
        cell.setupData(complex)
        cell.setupUI()
    }

    return cell

}
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if complexTable == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView{
        print("took from search") //Never called!!
        return self.complexSearchResults.count
    } else {
        print("took from all")
        return self.manager.complexArray.count
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare tableView that is passed to the functions with `searchResultsTableView` - not your local property `complexTable`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = complexTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(COMPLEX_IDENTIFIER) as! SideBarComplexCell

    var complexArray: Array<SidebarComplex>
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView { //<<<<<< HERE CHANGED
        complexArray = self.complexSearchResults
    } else {
        complexArray = self.manager.complexArray
    }

    if complexArray.count > indexPath.section {
        let complex = complexArray[indexPath.section]
        cell.setupData(complex)
        cell.setupUI()
    }
    return cell
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView { //<<<<<< HERE CHANGED
        return self.complexSearchResults.count
    } else {
       print("took from all")
       return self.manager.complexArray.count
    }
}
```

Comment: perffffect! thanks, will accept to solved once I can :D